# Proving if k-algebras are finitely generated and noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given two $k$-algebras $R:=k\oplus x^2 \, k[x] \subseteq k[x]$ and $S:= k\oplus xy \,\, k[x,y] \subseteq k[x,y]$ I need to show if they are finitely generated and if they are noetherian.

For $R$ to be finitely generated k-Algebra, we need to show that there exist finitely many elements, $a_1, a_2,....a_n$ such that $R=k[a_1,a_2,...a_n].$ But we know that it is contained in $k[x]$. For the second Question I Need to show if there is an ascending chain of ideals.

Can somebody give me a hint as how to proceed ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$R = k \oplus x^2 k[x] = k [ x^2, x^3 ]$

Also, $S$ is isomorphic to the semi-group algebra $k [ \mathbb N \times \mathbb N ]$, which is not a finitely generated semi-group.
None of the $(n, 1)$ can be written in terms of others. So $S$ is not Noetherian.